# os.path.join(*list) not working as expected when trying to convert a list to a path

Tags: python, list, path, os.path

I'm trying to convert this list:
`a_list = ['c:', 'project_files', 'ProjA', 'B_Files']`

into this path:
`'c:\\project_files\\ProjA\\B_Files'`

I'm using this:

```
a_list = ['c:', 'project_files', 'ProjA', 'B_Files']
my_path = os.path.join(*a_list)
```

However this is what I get:
`'c:project_files\\ProjA\\B_Files'`

Why isn't there a `\\` after `c:` ?
I was reading some similar questions and apparently it has something to do with this not being an absolute path but a relative one, but I'm still unsure how to get what I want

I'd appreciate any advice

Comment: This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered directly on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). Relevant section:

> Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` `(c:foo)`, not `c:\foo`.

Comment: Is there a way to get c:\foo ?

Comment: @ATP you have to specify it as an absolute path. So here you could use: `os.path.join("/", "c:", "foo")`